# Deploying React Website to s3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

New'ish to AWS very new to CI/CD.  And have a question re: deploying a Deploying React Website to an S3 Bucket.

I've got me a `Git` repo that contains a React web app.

I've setup an `AWS CodePipeline` project, which polls the master branch of the repo looking for commits.

It then triggers the `AWS CodeBuild` project which builds the react app as defined in the `buildspec.yml`

In the example/tutorial I've followed the `buildspec.yml` had the following...

```
post_build:
    commands:
      - aws s3 cp dist s3://${S3_BUCKET} --recursive
```

...which copies the build output to the destination `S3 Bucket`.

It all works great, however this assumes that the S3 Bucket is already there.

Question:  Which step should be responsible for creating the destination `S3 Bucket` and what should I be using to do so?

I'm thinking that perhaps it should be a `CodeDeploy` with another `Cloudformation` Template

Just after a little guidance before going down the wrong route :)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I think I found the tutorial you were referring to: https://www.karelbemelmans.com/2017/01/deploying-a-hugo-website-to-amazon-s3-using-aws-codebuild/

Can you specify two post_build commands? You could just create the bucket first which might fail if the bucket already exists but who cares right? Or you could check if the bucket exists and only if it doesn't create it. 
Here's the s3 command you need to create a bucket:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/create-bucket.html

There's an API for list buckets but I can't post it because this new user doesn't have 10 reputation yet unfortunately.

Good luck,
-Asaf